# Pandas - Input text into a column based on blank cells in a different column

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my code:

```
    finalCSV = pd.read_csv('pathName') #Open new CSV
#create col for isMAP based on true or false
    finalCSV['isMap'] = np.where(finalCSV['MAP'] == finalCSV['productPrice'], 'True', 'False')
    finalCSV = finalCSV.sort_values(by = ['isMap'], ascending = True,) #Make it so the falses come out first

if finalCSV['productSKU'].isna().all():
     finalCSV['isMap'].str.replace('False' ,'N/A')
finalCSV.to_csv('pathName', index = False) #Close and overwrite CSV
```

Here is the image of the csv file I'm working with 
[image]

What I want to do is input the text N/A on the column 'isMap' if the adjacent cell from 'productSKU' is null. However when I run my code snippet, the excel file keeps 'FALSE' instead of N/A

Edit: Here is the link to my CSV

https://drive.google.com/file/d/10Xnw33SbYmEgPC-UUBjJvrDMf0XfVtdq/view?usp=sharing

**Some Extra Clarification**

The first 3 columns are given, productName, productOMS, productPrice, productSKU, and productURL are all items that I got with my webscraper. isMap is a column that I'm creating in this program then dynamically filling it in with results.

So

```
if MAP == productPrice, isMap would return true
if MAP != productPrice isMap would return false
```

Now if my webscraper failed to get a productSKU and/or productName, then it would mean that the product does not exist on the website

```
if productSKU is NULL, isMap would return not available
```

Here is the DataFrame Head:

```
{'SKU': {0: 'FRC5131-WM-33', 275: 'KECOM-36', 276: 'DW-BS-24', 277: 'BS655N-48', 278: '8654WM-36'}, 

'MAP': {0: nan, 275: 779.95, 276: nan, 277: 1299.95, 278: 1295.95}, 


'productSKU': {0: nan, 275: nan, 276: nan, 277: nan, 278: nan}, 


'productPrice': {0: nan, 275: nan, 276: nan, 277: nan, 278: nan}, 


'productName': {0: nan, 275: nan, 276: nan, 277: nan, 278: nan}, 

'HOME DEPOT (OMSID)': {0: 312962522, 275: 206922074, 276: 308581002, 277: 312332575, 278: 309618527}, 

'productURL': {0: 'https://www.homedepot.com/p/312962522', 275: 'https://www.homedepot.com/p/206922074', 276: 'https://www.homedepot.com/p/308581002', 277: 'https://www.homedepot.com/p/312332575', 278: 'https://www.homedepot.com/p/309618527'}, 

'isMap': {0: 'False', 275: 'False', 276: 'False', 277: 'False', 278: 'False'}, 

'productOMS': {0: 312962522, 275: 206922074, 276: 308581002, 277: 312332575, 278: 309618527}}
```

Comment: I see a few things that are going on -- one of which is Pandas auto guessing the dtypes for each CSV column. Could you please edit your post to include the CSV file data?

Comment: The other -- and most important thing -- is that `.replace()` does not do the replacement inplace by default. See [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html#pandas.DataFrame.replace) -- `inplace` is `False` by default. The easiest fix seems to add `finalCSV['isMap'] = ` at the beginning of the line with the call to `.replace()`. But do post the CSV data first please :-) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This did the trick if anyone else has the same problem

```
finalCSV['isMap'] = np.where( finalCSV['productSKU'].isna(), "Not Available", finalCSV['isMap'])
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

For the CSV file you posted, `finalCSV['productSKU'].isna().all()` is `False` -- on rows 7 and 9, there are values in the `productSKU` column.

Manually deleting those 2 values creates an error as the 
`isMap` column was auto detected to be a `bool` type.

The other confusing thing is that the string `N/A` is interpreted by Pandas as a "not a number" value...! See the documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) under `na_values`.

I recommend using something other than `N/A` as the resulting value. :-) Original answer with fixed code below.

---

The fix seems to be:

```py
finalCSV = pd.read_csv(pathName, dtype={'isMap': str}) #Open new CSV

is_na_index = finalCSV['isMap'][finalCSV['productSKU'].isna()].index

finalCSV.loc[is_na_index, 'isMap'] = finalCSV.loc[is_na_index, 'isMap'].replace('FALSE', 'Not Available')

finalCSV.to_csv(pathName, index = False) #Close and overwrite CSV
```

Comment: that didn't do the trick, I'll post part of my CSV Data as an edit with the post

Comment: sorry how can I upload the file to stackoverflow

Comment: dont upload the file. do a dataframe.head().to_dict() and paste the output

Comment: @sammywemmy I think I got it i just did the code print(finalCSV.head().tp_dict()

Comment: @chrisHG take a look again please -- I amended the code. There were a few things going on at once -- namely, the `isMap` column's type being detected as bool, and then the `N/A` string being detected as a "not a number" value. See if the above code works (and please make sure to edit rows 7 and 9 as they do contain values for the `productSKU` column)

Comment: @GregSadetsky That is still giving me False instead of N/A

Comment: Also some rows will have a SKU and I would want FALSE to be in the isMap col instead of NA

Comment: Oh! Your `.isna().all()` call is checking if all values are empty...

Comment: so how would I only check the empty values? Sorry I should have clarified that in my post

Comment: Working on this now :-)

Comment: I'm also looking into some stuff and I added how I populated isMap if that would help in any way

Comment: Ok, just fixed it -- it will now replace 'FALSE' only for the empty `productSKU`

Comment: Did you test in on your machine, it kept the same results on mine

Comment: I did test the code I posted yes. Just did it again: 1) downloaded the CSV file whose URL you posted 2) took the code I posted here and added a line to import pandas, and another line to set pathName to the CSV file path 3) ran python3 on the script -- just to be sure, I'm using Python 3.7.5 and Pandas 1.0.3 --- 4) checked the CSV file. All `isMap` values are `Not Available` for those rows that don't have a productSKU.

Comment: The only thing that I'm not doing is running the extra code which you added in the edit -- the one that creates the isMap column dynamically. In your CSV file, the `MAP` column never matches the `productPrice` column... what are you trying to do..? :-)

Comment: @GregSadetsky First thanks for the help! Second, The data I am given can have a MAP and productPrice. If it does and those values match up then isMap is a column that I created and it would be populated with Trues. If MAP and productPrice don't match then isMap would be populated with Falses.  Items without a productSKU are items that do not exist on the website that I am scraping from, so I would like to populate isMap with 'Not Availables'  I'll clarify it more on my post.